# At what layer in the protocol stack does DNS happen?

Tags: http, tcp, dns

Let's use a browser as an example.  HTTP requests do not need to contain any IP addresses.  So would www.example.com be translated into an IP address at the TPC layer?

## EDIT

Seems like DNS is used to tell TCP which IP address to connect to.  So does HTTP call DNS?

With this stack:

HTTP

---

DNS

---

TCP

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_network_protocols_%28OSI_model%29

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: You can post it here https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ network version of stackoverflow

Answer (score 25, accepted):

DNS is a protocol that arguably sits at the application-level, but is a separate application in and of itself that makes use of the whole TCP/IP "stack".  (LDAP is similar, if that helps "place" DNS.)  It's a fundamental "phone book"-like directory for the Internet and has absolutely nothing specific to do with the HTTP protocol.  DNS uses UDP and TCP transport to query other distributed DNS servers to answer client questions like "what IP addresses are associated with the name www.google.com?".   Once a client application, like a web browser, has an IP address with which to connect, DNS is then out of the picture.  The browser opens up a TCP connection to the IP address and then initiates the HTTP protocol over that TCP transport session to talk web stuff.

Answer (score 13):

In OSI stack terms, DNS runs *in parallel* to HTTP in the *Application Layer* (layer 7).

DNS is in effect an application that is invoked to help out the HTTP application, and therefore does not sit "below" HTTP in the OSI stack.

DNS itself also makes use of UDP and more rarely TCP, both of which in turn use IP.

Comment: but isnt DNS server technically in another network, so to go from HTTP to DNS do we go directly from application to application or from application to transport to network to physical then to physical of DNS.... @Alnitak

Comment: @iajnr This is what is meant by "uses services provided by". The layers are abstractions.

Answer (score 3):

Application Layer - #7 of OSI

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_network_protocols_(OSI_model)

In response to your latest edit:

Doesn't DNS use UDP to send a response indicating any details of the requested IP (unless a certain size threshold is crossed 512bytes).

Comment: I meant that the results of DNS are used for communication over TCP.
I was not saying that the communication with the DNS server happens over TCP.

Answer (score 3):

I'd advise you to download and install wireshark.  Run wireshark and visit some websites.  You can see how DNS works.  DNS (as already mentioned) is handled at the application layer.  Almost all high level languages have libraries for the function 'gethostbyname'.

```
    Python 3.3.3 (default, Nov 26 2013, 13:33:18) 
    [GCC 4.8.2] on linux
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import socket
    >>> socket.gethostbyname("stackoverflow.com")
   '198.252.206.16'
```

Take a browser for example, after acquiring the host from the DNS server using some form of gethostbyname, a standard TCP socket connection is established and the browser/webserver communicate over HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

Well technically the client computer is the first to be "asked" which IP address should link to which domain name.

Which involves the term DNS resolver. Essentially it searches through previous queries which are cached on a clients computer and if it finds a match then it returns what would essentially be a normal DNS lookup (without leaving your local network to find an answer/address). You can actually edit this file on your own computer and the URL of your web browsers will actually show your changes.

Comment: Does an HTTP request start this process?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the OSI it is the Application layer - layer 7